# how to print the string with out truncating the white space at end

Tags: php, html

How to print the string with out truncating the white space at end.
I need to print set of fields with out truncating white space.

```
//eg
$test="test     ";
```

I need to print the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the function for the expected output.

```
 <?php
 $input = "Alien";
 echo str_pad($input, 10);                      // produces "Alien     "
 echo str_pad($input, 10, "-=", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // produces "-=-=-Alien"
 echo str_pad($input, 10, "_", STR_PAD_BOTH);   // produces "__Alien___"
 echo str_pad($input, 6 , "___");               // produces "Alien_"
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to print whitespace in HTML, you'd better use `<pre>` or even `<table>` if you're printing table data. If it isn't table data, but mark-up, you'd better use CSS to add space.

So the best solution depends on the purpose. Using `str_replace` to change the spaces to non breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) is probably the easiest, but doubtly the best.

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace space characters with HTML non breaking spaces - e.g.:

```
$test="test     ";
echo str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Print where exactly?

You can replace a space with `&nbsp;`

```
echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $test);
```

or you can use

```
echo "<pre>$test</pre>";
```

Comment: `str_replace` is much better in this case.

Comment: @Shakti Singh: Right, meant to write that one! Low battery, though! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',"test     ");
```